# Two-way adapters

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

In GoF there is a two way adapter concept:

> A potential problem with adapters is that they aren't transparent to
>   all clients. An adapted object no longer conforms to the Adaptee
>   interface, so it can't be used as is wherever an Adaptee object can.
>   Two-way adapters can provide such transparency. Specifically, they're
>   useful when two different clients need to view an object differently.

Doesn't it violate the SRP as there are two reasons for the adapter to change such as when it should new functionality to conform `Interface1` and anther for `Interface2`?

Comment: It depends on how you define 'Single Responsibility'. A two way adapter adapts two interfaces. A change to an adapted interface could reasonably be considered the one reason to change.

Also,  adapters are by design glue code. Glue code, like real world glue, can be messy.

Comment: @KristianH I can write the whole Photoshop in one class and say that this class has single responsibility. It makes Photoshop work as it should. SRP is concrete - once reason for class to change, in other words - once source of change.

Comment: @Narek-When you come up with a clear and succinct definition of "One reason for a class to change" or "single responsibility" that the majority of developers can agree with then you should write a book and go on the convention circuit. The problem is that by their very nature both those concepts are recursive and there's no "correct" definition. No matter how low you go someone can always find 2 reasons to change. Likewise, someone can always find 2 responsibilities. If a single Photoshop class does a single responsibility as the developer defines it in their App then it meets SRP in that App.